# Can we see the storage account used by Azure SQL Database internally for storing MDF/LDF and Backup files?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

As **Azure SQL Database** has two layers. One for **Compute** and other for **Storage**.

Storage layer stores MDF/LDF file in a Storage Account. Can we see the storage account that is used by Azure SQL Database to store these files and also the .BAK files that are generated as part of point in time backup for 7 days (without need of any storage account configuration)?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-sql/database/high-availability-sla#basic-standard-and-general-purpose-service-tier-locally-redundant-availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All information related to automated backups and the storage used by Azure SQL is not available to customers as it is managed by Azure behind the scenes, and that is part of the benefits of using platform as a service.

For example, when you go to the restore a database on the portal you can see the options that you have and you can only select to which point in time you want to restore. This is part of the idea of getting a platform as a service (PaaS)... it is managed for you. You only need to choose the point in time and the Azure service should map it to the internal file(s) behind the scene. As those files are managed by Azure you cannot see them or see their attributes, that type of information is available on IaaS, not on PaaS or SaaS.

If you want more control about backup files on Azure SQL, choose to backup databases to storage accounts using export feature or using SqlPackage utility or using Azure Automation.